# Nginx reverse proxy with node docker seems not working

Tags: docker, nginx, url, path, args

I set up a docker containing a nodejs server and which receives arguments from a path. I can communicate well with my docker instance when I run a curl command (I have an error message, but this is normal)

[image: curl ation]

I'm trying to communicate with my docker instance from the outside with my Nginx server, but I'm having some problems.
Indeed, when I enter the access url, I get a 404 error. My configuration file looks like this.
[image]

when I try I go to the access url, I do have a 404 error.
[image]

My concern is on the "location" part of my configuration, but I don't really see how to solve the problem. If you have any leads, I'll take them :)

Comment: Did you tried accessing with http?

Comment: I only go through https

Comment: proxy_redirect http:// https://;   add it right after proxy_pass

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Before the proxy pass try to add this  `rewrite ^/myurl(/.*)$ $1 last;`

Comment: sorry, it's not working, and in my yolo log, I see anything ...I'll see about the logs and keep looking for :)

Comment: @ghovat: it's working...the configuration was not taken into account because of my file name.